# How to debug whitelisted Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I have completed Google's form to enable my device to be whitelisted and have been provided with an AppID.

I have followed the procedures outlined here to try and debug the device with no success:
https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver#debugging

I am able to ping my device by the IP, but connecting to port 9222 results in failure.  Telnet to that port is also unsuccessful.

Does anyone know why this might not be working?  I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Validate the device serial number, eg. Z can be mistaken for a 2, and O for 0.

Comment: @Gatada very true. I mistook a 6 for an 8

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 16):

The problem was that my Chromecast device was not sending the serial number to Google.

I was able to get it to work by enabling the sending of the devices serial number in the Windows settings utility (changing this setting in the android app didn't seem to work).  After changing the setting I rebooted the device, and now I can connect on port 9222.  I am not sure why this isn't in the developer walk through... or maybe I missed it?

Comment: Actually it is, I found it here as almost the first thing to do: https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting

Comment: When you say you can connect on 9222, does that mean you are connecting via telnet?  I can ping my chromecast, but cant telnet to it, or connect via browser on that port.  I do have the option selected to send the serial number.  Of course I have no way of knowing that the serial number google has on file actually matches.  Wish they had an actual portal to manage devices and appid's for the chromecast.

Comment: Same issue as Anthony's. Can ping to the dongle, can cast a Youtube video via curl, but cannot connect Chrome to port 9222.

Comment: I just want to reiterate...make sure to reboot after updating the settings in the Chromecast app. It seems like the settings save when clicking the done button, but are not applied until a reboot.

Answer (score 7):

I only got this option when I opened "Options" in the Google Cast Extension inside Chrome and then clicked on the blue icon about a dozen times very quickly.  Suddenly a new option appeared at the bottom where I could enter the hostname of my whitelisted URL:

[image: Chrome Cast Extension Magic Options]

I also made sure that "send serial number" was enabled in the Chromecast.app (and make sure to reboot!)

[image: Chromecast.app settings]

Now, I am able to hit port 9222 in a browser and can see my app at http://{my-chromcast-ip}:9222/. I can use dev tools in Chrome to debug, refresh the page, inspect on-screen elements, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Something else that I haven't seen others mention yet.  If you're going to the right IP and getting the link to remote debugging, but you don't see your source, elements, etc.  It could be blocked by security settings.  This stumped me for a while until I noticed a small shield icon in my url bar.  Click on this and allow it to load sources.  Once I did that everything populated as expected.

Comment: Every time I return to chrome cast development, I forget this one! Everything seems to work, but no logs, elements etc. appear until you do this. Thank you brockoli.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a bit with this one. I think some things might have changed with the last firmware update on the Chromecast. I could connect to port 9222 after I did the following:

Registered the custom receiver and host it on the outside of my network (on Google Drive: 
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

Launch the receiver. I used the Chromecast example https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome

Make sure the app ID in chromehellotext.html is the one registered on your account.

When After this, I could connect to the debugging port.

The port is only open when your custom receiver is running on the Chromecast.

I also might be useful to enable debugging on the chrome extension. This will show what's going on between the Chromecast and sender:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an ancient question, however my answer might help people searching in the future.

Simply rebooting the Chromecast after having set up my details in the Cast console helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast to a custom receiver first (at least once) before trying to access the IP with debug port. Otherwise debugging won't be enabled.